# How can I set a fixed location for text so when it grows it still be in a center?

Tags: text, javafx, integer, location, label

When integer is changed the text contained it changes its location. I want that it be at the same position as when int equals to 100. Even when it equals to 5. Here is my code :

```
Stage priceStage = new Stage();
priceStage.setResizable(false);
priceStage.setWidth(450);
priceStage.setHeight(450);
priceStage.setTitle(windowTitle);

IntegerProperty price, maxIncome, adLevel;

price = new SimpleIntegerProperty(priceDifference);
maxIncome = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
adLevel = new SimpleIntegerProperty(1);
Button goButton = new Button("Организовать!");

Text assignPriceText = new Text("   Цена на одного студента: ");
assignPriceText.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 30));

Text plus = new Text("+");
Text minus = new Text("-");
Text priceInfo = new Text();

Text priceText = new Text();
Text studentsAmmountText = new Text();
Text maxIncomeText = new Text();
Text adLevelText = new Text();

priceText.textProperty().bind(price.asString("%d $"));
studentsAmmountText.textProperty().bind(studentsAmmount.asString("\nКоличество студентов: %d"));
maxIncomeText.textProperty().bind(maxIncome.asString("\nДоход: %d $"));
adLevelText.textProperty().bind(adLevel.asString("\nРеклама: %d %% \n"));

TextFlow priceTextFlow = new TextFlow(minus, priceText, plus, studentsAmmountText, maxIncomeText, adLevelText);
priceTextFlow.setPadding(new Insets(0,0,0,50));

plus.setFill(Color.RED);
minus.setFill(Color.RED);

plus.setFont(Font.font(80));
minus.setFont(Font.font(80));
priceText.setFont(Font.font(100));
studentsAmmountText.setFont(Font.font(30));
maxIncomeText.setFont(Font.font(30));
adLevelText.setFont(Font.font(30));
goButton.setFont(Font.font(30));
```

As you can see from pictures, when number is 75 there is a useless space which I indicated by red line. But when number is 100 it is perfectly located at the center. So how can I make text automatically changes its position when number changes?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a StackPane. Add the label to StackPane. Well in this case it looks like your TextFlow should be added to a StackPane. I am guessing you can make the StackPane width be the same as its parent's width(bound to parent's width). Then set the TextFlow width to be less than min width of the StackPane.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution :

```
price.addListener((c, o, n)->{
    space.setPrefWidth(120-30*String.valueOf(n).length());
});
```

I have added listener to the price (not text, but IntegerProperty) and everytime when there is a new digit added to number, space (Region) is reduced as much as the size of space of new digit. It equals to 30. So I convert new number to string for defining its length, then I multiple it to 30 and reduce space.